# In which sorah the Following ayat is in Quran?

Tags: quran, reference-request

In which Sarah/Verse the Following ayat is in Quran?

> Ina'Allaha LA Yakhfa Alaihe Shai'un Fil Arde wala Fisamaa
>
> إِنَّ اللَّـهَ لَا يَخْفَىٰ عَلَيْهِ شَيْءٌ فِي الْأَرْضِ وَلَا فِي السَّمَاءِ

I am finding the ayat but didn't found it, I need your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sura Aale Imran ayah 5 - http://tanzil.net/#3:5

إِنَّ اللَّـهَ لَا يَخْفَىٰ عَلَيْهِ شَيْءٌ فِي الْأَرْضِ وَلَا فِي السَّمَاءِ

Indeed, from Allah nothing is hidden in the earth nor in the heaven.